# Htaccess not rewritting file in sub directories

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following codes in my htaccess file which removes .php extension from page name and redirect to a 404 page when a trailing slash is inserted at the end of a page name in the following directories.

1. example.com/file [redirecting]
2. example.com/file/ [not redirecting]
3. example.com/folder/file [redirecting]
4. example.com/folder/file/ [not redirecting]
5. example.com/folder/folder/file [not redirecting]
6. example.com/folder/folder/file/ [not redirecting]

I have tried several htaccess codes but **5.** doesn't redirects. I will like **5.** to be redirecting like **1. and 3.**

**CODE**

```
# error pages
ErrorDocument 203 /error/203.php
ErrorDocument 204 /error/204.php
ErrorDocument 301 /error/301.php
ErrorDocument 400 /error/400.php
ErrorDocument 401 /error/401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.php
ErrorDocument 405 /error/405.php
ErrorDocument 406 /error/406.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error/500.php
ErrorDocument 502 /error/503.php
ErrorDocument 503 /error/503.php
ErrorDocument 504 /error/504.php

Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

# remove .php 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

# rewrite index page
RewriteRule ^login index.php [NC,L]

# rewrite profile page
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

# site.com/profile.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)$ profile.php?tg_u=$1 [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

# block access to htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: The .htaccess code you provided converts `http://www.example1.com/folder/folder/file` to `http://www.example1.com/folder/folder/file.php` successfully. Are you sure that both folders and the file are actually created on the server? That is the only reason I think this would not work, give both your `RewriteCond`.

Comment: ok @GaryThomas i just update my code with my full htaccess code.